# Unreal Engine 4 C++ - How to make an actor move up and down along the Z axis

Tags: c++, actor, unreal-engine4

I am new to the Unreal 4 engine and I'm struggling with some things concerning the coding part as I want an actor to move down and up as soon as it reaches a certain height. Here's what I've done so far:

```
void APickup::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
    FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation();
    NewLocation.Z += (DeltaTime * 20.f);
    SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
}
```

I don't get how I can make this work whether with an "If" statement or a "bool" statement. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Update: 
The actor stops at a certain height and doesn't move, I need it to go down now. Here's the code:

```
if(NewLocation.Z <300)
{
    NewLocation.Z +=(DeltaTime * 100.f);
    SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
```

Comment: Do you mean `if (NewLocation.Z > CertainHeight) { NewLocation.Z += ... }`?

Comment: Yes exactly, if NewLocation.Z reaches certain height, stop it and make it go down.

Comment: Or maybe use a bool command?

Comment: What do you mean by bool command?

Comment: If the statement is true, then make the actor go down, or if the statement is false do the same

Comment: But that's precisely what an "if" does

Comment: Yes correct, I tried your code but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your question is more related to how to do things in C++ than Unreal Engine itself.

Using if statements you can check whether you are above certain height or below. However, if you want to have your actor moving up and down you'll need to keep some sort of inner state. Add for instance a `bool` member variable to keep track of this. In your class declaration (.h file)

```
class APickup {
  // ...other things...

  bool bImGoingUp = true;
};
```

Then in your Tick function check whether you are going up or down and update your height accordingly. Here you need to check too if you are above or below your Z range, and change your moving direction if so. Say you want to move between [-50, 50] (btw, Unreal uses always centimeters)

```
void APickup::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
  Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
  FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation();
  if (NewLocation.Z > 50.0f) {
    bImGoingUp = false;
  } else if (NewLocation.Z < -50.0f) {
    bImGoingUp = true;
  }
  float factor = (bImGoingUp ? 20.f : -20.f);
  NewLocation.Z += factor * DeltaTime;
  SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
}
```

You also need to make sure your actor starts the game within this range or might ended up going up or down forever.

This is just a basic example, if you want to make it really robust you'll need to elaborate a bit more your logic. You could too for instance look at your actor's direction of movement to see if you are moving up or down instead of using a boolean.

Comment: The actor keeps going up despite using your code, and by certain height you mean just a number right?

Comment: Yes, certain height is just the height you want your actor to start going down. It should be an absolute Z value in the world coordinates (in centimeters). Select something in the editor at the height you want and check its Z value

Comment: Even with the certain height it keeps going up, it doesn't go down, This is such a pain in the a**

Comment: Update: The actor is stopping but it won't go down

Comment: Oh yes, the moment it goes below certain height it starts going up again

Comment: No I meant the actor is stopping completely at some height, it won't move at all, but now I need it to go down. I've added the following:

    if (NewLocation.Z <300)
    {
    NewLocation.Z -= (DeltaTime *100.f);
    SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
    }

Comment: Ok yes, I totally overlooked the actual problem you meant. With this is not enough because the moment you start going down, you are below your desired height then the actor moves up again and repeat, then it looks like it doesn't move. You need to keep some inner state

Comment: That's my problem right now, it doesn't want to go down at all. How do I keep the inner state?

Comment: That seem to have worked perfectly! You saved me from a really big trouble, I owe you a really big thanks! Thank you mate!